# Reference in a poster

Tags: poster, self-citation

I am presenting a poster in an international conference based on a work that is yet to be published. Should I include this work in the references of the poster?

Comment: What do you mean by " based on"? Is it a next step after that work, or a preliminary step towards it?

Comment: I am presenting the findings that we have so far. This will also appear in the paper that is yet to be submitted for publication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to another answer here, I'll suggest that, yes, you should make a reference to the work in progress. This will enable anyone seeing the poster to be on the lookout for the later, more complete, work.

If you have a working title for the finished work, especially one unlikely to change, then list it that way and mark it in the citation as "in progress" and/or "to be submitted". If it has been submitted, but not yet published, mark it as "submitted" or, if it has been accepted, as "to appear...".

If you don't have a working title, you can just indicate somewhere that this is incomplete work, still in progress. Again, this is just a service to those who might be especially interested in following up on the work.

Comment: It's unlikely to hurt, but unless the author list and/or working title of the paper is clearly different from the poster's, it seems rather redundant to have an "in progress" reference. It is certainly worth noting on the poster if the work has been accepted, but I've often seen this done as a note under the title rather than in a list of references.

Answer (score 4):

Usually (in my field), the point of a poster is to share works-in-progress. People occasionally present previously published work but it is much less common. So I doubt that anyone would be looking for a reference to a full paper on a poster.

Plus, if there isn't a publication, there really isn't anything to reference. You are presenting *that work* as a poster. It would be a bit circular to reference a hypothetical future publication in a poster presenting part of the same project. If you have a pre-print it might be nice to include a link or reference to that, but it doesn't sounds like you're that far along.

So no, unless I'm misunderstanding your situation, you should not include a reference to the current project.

Answer (score 0):

If the reference is to a paper that we might get around to submitting when we're done, then no. Maybe there's another conference presentation to reference? If it's really in the process of preparation, then yes, if you want to advertise it. If it's your paper, then it's even good form to have a sign up sheet to be sent a copy once it's ready.

If it's to work that everybody knows about but you know may take forever if that (my field has a few of those), you can reference "procrastinating friend of mine, unpublished".